# Problemas con consulta sql a eloquen en laravel 5.5

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy traduciendo esta consulta.

```
select usuario_ad, count(usuario_ad) 
from usuarios 
where usuario_ad in (select username 
                     from users where users.refer="Thor" 
                     union select "Thor") 
group by (usuario_ad);
```

y esta esta en eloquent.

```
$uno = User::where('refer', 'thor')
           ->select('username')
           ->union('thor');
Usuarios::select('usuario_ad')
       ->count('usuario_ad')
       ->whereIn('usuario_ad', $uno)->groupby(usuario_ad);
```

Tengo un error con el whereIn, al parecer solo se aceptan id, pero no que sentencia poner para que me admita lo que necesito arriba.

> PHP Error:  Call to a member function whereIn() on integer in Psy
>   Shell code on line 1

Bueno, he tenido que modificar algunas cosas para resolver errores, sin embargo ahora tengo uno que no he podido arreglar.

```
$conteo = DB::table('users')->where('refer', 'Thor')->select('username')- 
      >get()->push('Thor');
             $conteo = (string) $conteo;
              $data = DB::table('usuarios')
              ->selectRaw('usuario_ad, count(usuario_ad) as Conteo')
              ->whereIn('usuario_ad', $conteo)
              ->groupBy('usuario_ad')
              ->paginate(20);
              $data = (string) $data;
```

"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Sospecho que el foreach() no puede leer un array en este caso $data y dentro de el otro array que es $conteo, no se si sera por otra causa

Comment: No deshagas la edición, es para mejorarla y hacerla entendible, pues así como la tienes el código se ve como simple texto

Comment: Lo siento aprendiz... gracias por la correcciòn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trata con la consulta de este modo:

```
$data = DB::table('usuarios')
          ->selectRaw('usuario_ad', 'count(usuario_ad) as Conteo')
          ->whereIn('usuario_ad', function($query){
                $query->select('username')
                      ->from('users')
                      ->where('users.refer', 'Thor')
                      ->union('Thor');
          })->groupBy('usuario_ad')->get();
```

- Usa el método `selectRaw()` para elegir que columnas retornar y además poder pasar instrucciones SQL como el caso de `count()`.
- El método `whereIn()` acepta 2 parámetros, el primero es la columna y el segundo en este caso la subquery de donde obtendremos los valores.
- Usa el `groupBy()` por fuera de la subquery para agrupar los resultados.
- Finalmente obtén los resultados con el método `get()`.

Comment: Muchas gracias Aprendiz.. notablemente mucho mejor la estructura de la consulta, pero sale este error con el corchete,

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Comment: @zereft me hacía falta un punto y coma, trata de nuevo

Comment: Gracias aprendiz... ahora sale otro error.


Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::selectRaw() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\laragon\www\arreglo\app\Http\Controllers\CuentaController.php on line 46

Comment: En cuanto pueda reviso dicho error

Comment: Muchas gracias.. también investigare...

Comment: He puesto esta linea ->selectRaw('usuario_ad, count(usuario_ad) as Conteo'), con dos comillas, el error ya no esta.. ahora sale este.


"Call to a member function getBindings() on string"

Comment: Usa el selectRaw solo para el COUNT  otro select simple para el usuario_ad

Comment: Muy bien, los separe... pero aun sale ese error, "Call to a member function getBindings() on string,  esta señalando esta linea  1602 $this->addBinding($query->getBindings(), 'union');